# Include changes the layout

Tags: minipage, include

Maybe this question is a bit specific, but it's an issue I have ran into recently.

So I have a larger document with multiple sections from different tex files. I simply include those files in the main document with \include{1_1.tex} and so on. The content of the files is mostly minipages with some definitions, pictures and so on. (It's mostly enumerations with each item being a minipage.)

So here is what works:

```
\include{1_1.tex}
\include{1_2.tex}
```

This will look perfectly fine, the layout will look as expected.

```
\include{2_1.tex}
\include{2_2.tex}
\include{2_3.tex}
```

This also looks good and the pictures and blocks of text are as I imagined.

However, if I try to include everything:

```
% section 1
\include{1_1.tex}
\include{1_2.tex}
% section 2
\include{2_1.tex}
\include{2_2.tex}
\include{2_3.tex}
```

The layout from section 1 will look good, but section 2 will be messed up. Page breaks will occur where there weren't any before, minipages that just fit on a page will be pushed to the next page and so on.

Can someone imagine what might cause the problem or is it maybe a specific issue with my document? Ultimately a workaround would be compiling everything independently and pasting the PDF pages together, but that's a bit annoying.

Comment: use `\include{2_1}` not `\include{2_1.tex}` (adding `.tex` is an error although I'm not sure it would have the effect described normally)

Comment: don't you get warnings `No file 2_1.tex.tex` ???

Comment: Without seeing anything of the code we can of course only guess. Maybe some definitions of one of the files is leaking out of the file and causes knock-on effects. Though in that case it would be weird to see only the `2` chapter compile OK. Try narrowing down the source of the problem by building an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Comment: what I can imagine is that in end of `1_2.tex` there is some thing that cause the problem.

Comment: To debug, what happens if you put curly brackets around the include statement, e.g. `{\include{1_2.tex}}`?  This should prevent definitions of leaking out of one file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was due to an unprotected setting of \arraystretch in one of the included files

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".